# How do I determine the selected row in a WPF datagrid using C#

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How do I determine the selected row in a WPF datagrid using C#

Comment: You need the DataGridRow or the SelectedItem?

Comment: IsSelected property of DataGrid becomes true when you select any Row of datagrid

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `DataGrid.SelectedItem`?